# How to stop access to file while it is being uploded by FTP on Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

I'm using FTP 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2. 
When I upload a file and it is partially uploaded I'm able to move it before it has completed. Is there a way to stop this?
I see an option under Advanced settings->Behaviour->File Handling->Allow reading files while uploading but this doesn't seem to do the trick. I guess it's write access that I need to stop.

It seemed to have this functionality by default on IIS6.

Answer (score 0):

It's described here how to do it:
[Secure Content in IIS Through File System ACLs](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/583/secure-content-in-iis-through-file-system-acls/)

You need to go to location on the file system where you have the website, mostly C:\inetpub\ftproot, and remove the write permission there. You need to do this for the IUSR account.

Answer (score 0):

We just give our files a bogus extension, like zipx, while the file is being copied.  Once the file is completely there just send an FTP command to rename it to the correct extension, like zip.  Now your other program can process the new file.